# Aux Scan descriptors in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am writing a query for Sybase (unionize query). Now according to Sybase article there is one aux scan descriptor for each table in the query and considering that I have 100 queries with 3 tables/query it should have 300 aux scan descriptors.
But when I run the query it says that it requires 303 aux scan descriptors. Somehow the extra 3 aux scan descriptors is a variable number. Previously I use to get error saying it required 305 descriptors. I went through their documentation but did not find anything helpful. Can anyone explain how this variable number that is added?

Another case is when I set aux scan descriptors to 278 and run the query, The query runs successfully. 25 descriptors are added to the value that I had set using the below command

```
sp_configure "aux scan descriptors", x
```

Can anyone give some pointers on this?

Answer (score 1):

The 'extra' scan descriptors are likely for worktables, the number of which can vary based on the query plan generated by the optimizer.

Comment: so there is no way to find the number before the query is run?

Comment: not really; as I mentioned in your other thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361888/finding-total-number-of-tables-in-union-query/44191502#44191502 - I suggest you consider redesigning your query/process, eg, instead of trying to jam everything into a single, monolithic union query why not just run 100 separate queries?  this would eliminate a) the need to know the max number of tables in a query and b) the need to worry about having enough aux scan descriptors, and of course you'll likely get much better performance